# get an extra parameter in my actionresult

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

Been looking ( maybe in the wrong place) , but I'm wondering how do I give a parameter from my actionlink to my controller.

This is my actionlink

```
 <li>@Html.ActionLink("MyEpisodes", "Index", "Paging")</li>
```

And this is my function in my controller

```
  public ActionResult Index(int? page, string condition)
        {
// do stuff
```

So does anybody have an idea how to get my parameter condition from the actionlink?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@Html.ActionLink("MyEpisodes", "Index", "Paging", new { condition = "..." }, null)
```

---

When passing both the controller name ("Paging") and routeValues to ActionLink you also need to pass null to the last parameter so it uses the correct `ActionLink` overload:

```
public static MvcHtmlString ActionLink(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string linkText, string actionName, string controllerName, object routeValues, object htmlAttributes)
```

instead of the wrong one:

```
public static MvcHtmlString ActionLink(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string linkText, string actionName, object routeValues, object htmlAttributes)
```

Comment: thanks ! that was my problem as well ( sorry forgot to mention that)

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
<li>@Html.ActionLink("MyEpisodes", "Index", "Paging", new {page = 1, condition = "poor"}, null)</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the overload of ActionLink that accept `object routeValues` as well. So something like this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("MyEpisodes", "Index", "Paging", new{ condition = "MyCondition});
```